# Prevent same users to login in different system at the same time

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, authentication, backend

The same user and password can be used from unlimited computers at the same time!!
if person 1 is logged in with a certain username and person 2 logs in a different computer or browser, with the same username and password, Person 1 is not logged out automatically!!! and they both work with the same user without any disturbance!!!

i need to prevent that and read many posts about it.
not gonna pay for a paid module to do that.

Identifing the session number using session_id() will not help because when person 1 is logged in with the user and person 2 logs in with the same user on different computer/browser, they have different session id , so i can't identify that the person 1 is already logged in and kill his session.

also the solution to add a new field "login_status" and when person 1 logs in , set it to 1 and when person 2 tries to log in, to check the field and block him if login_status is 1, won't work, because i can't update this field in cases when the user just closes the browser window and doesn't push the logout link.

THIS IS A HUGE AND CRITICAL PROBLEM!

any tips and help will be very much appreciated.

thank you.

I used JWT token for Authentication and I am using nodeJs in backend and angular in frontend and mongoDb as database.

Answer (score 1):

One other solution to only allow one concurrent session for every user is to close the exisiting session when you log in from a different device.

So if a user has a session running on device 1 and logs in on device 2 the session on device 1 will be deleted and a new session for device 2 will be created.

This also solves the problem you pointed out of not logging out. It does not matter if the user does not log out. The session will be closed when a new session is created from a different device.

Comment: You are suggesting me to add session in backend ?

Comment: Yes, save the user session in the backend. Or if not the session some value that you can use to tell the frontend to expire a session when a new one with the same user from a different device is detected.